# Who to access the property from Environment?

Tags: java, spring, spring-framework-beans

I have a very old Spring Framework 5.0 based project, recently I tried to add some feature to it. It has xml based configuration with `context:property-placeholder` to load the properties files.

And now I created an new Java based @Configuration file, tried to access the properties which loaded by the XML. I found I can use @Value to wired the value to variable, but can't find them in the `@Autowired Environment env`.

config/application.prroperties:

```
key1=value1
key2=value2
```

application.xml

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:config/application.properties"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example" />
```

Java configuration

```
@Configuration
class MyConfiguration {
  @Autowired
  Environment env;           // Can't get "key1" and "key2"

  @Value("${key1}") key1;    // This is valid. it has been assigned with "value1"
  @Value("${key2}") key2;    // also work

  @Bean public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfigurer() { 
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer(); 
  }

  ...
}
```

I don't know why, and how I can make the `env` has those properties? Or any other way that allows me access the properties list? not wired them one by one?

Comment: Have you checked from the `Environment` which profile is active and from it the properties you are looking for? Everything is described in the doc: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/Environment.html